How to continuously insert new HTML into an HTML table using PHP
I am trying to develop a work tracker where I have a form at the top of my page and it inserts into an HTML table once submitted. I have achieved this however, I can only insert one row on the table. I would like to be able to 'add' more HTML to the document by submitting the form multiple times. Right now, a second submission of the form only rewrites the HTML.
I currently have my prepared statement as it should be, it inserts into the DB properly and displays in my first HTML table. I am currently using an echo approach to display the form in the table, but i would have to manually rewrite the php to display more table rows.
See form below (only some of the code in attempt to keep this short):
 <form class="addWork" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <label class="">Customer</label>
                    <input type="text" name="addCustomer" class="<?php echo (!empty($customer_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $customer_err; ?></span> 
                </div>

                <div class="col">   
                    <label class="">Site Code / Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="addSite" class="<?php echo (!empty($site_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $site_err; ?></span> 
                </div>

See Table below:
<section class="tables mt-5 container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <table class="tbaytel-table">
                    <caption>TBayTel</caption>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Site Code / Name</th>
                        <th>Urgency</th>
                        <th>Outage Descrption</th>
                        <th>Date Requested</th>
                        <th>Aging in days</th>  
                        <th>Requested By</th>
                        <th>Comments</th> 
                        <th>Status</th> 
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        if($customer ==='TBayTel'){
                            echo "
                            <tr>
                                 <td>$siteCode</td> 
                                 <td>$urgency</td>
                                 <td>$outage</td> 
                                 <td>$date</td>
                                 <td></td>
                                 <td>$requestedBy</td>
                                 <td>$comments</td>
                            </tr>
                            ";
                        };
                    ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

How can I rewrite my code to 'insert' new HTML every time the form is submitted? Ideally, I would like to remove the table row once work is complete, but not remove from the DB. So fetching from DB is not the approach I would like to take.

If you're submitting a form, the script will need to generate the entire table each time it's called, not just the addition.

but not remove from the DB...well you could mark is as "complete" in the DB once the work is done, and then have a query which doesn't select rows marked as complete. But yeah since every request is a fresh start generating a new page, you have to rebuild the whole table from some data source each time the form is submitted, as well as when you first load the page. Or you could redesign it using an ajax-based approach so you can just change the specific html elements you want, and communicate with the server asynchronously without refreshing the whole page.

@ADyson so using this approach I would mysqli_fetch_assoc the DB table, add a "complete" row to the DB and only show data without "complete" selected?

broadly yes. I assumed that the form you've shown us here would submit data to PHP, which would then insert that data into the database as a new work item. Next (including at the page loading time, when the form hasn't been submitted yet) you'd run a SQL query to select all the rows in the database which aren't marked as complete (eg. SELECT * FROM work WHERE completed = 0, or something of that nature) and output the HTML table based on that

I also assume at some point you'll add a button (or whatever) to each row of the table allowing you to submit a work item to PHP as being completed, and the PHP code which receives that would update the relevant database row to set the completed field to 1, and then it would go and run the above-mentioned SELECT query again in order to output the latest version of the table (which would of course then exclude the newly-completed item)

@ADyson yeah that's correct. My submit button currently inserts into the data base and then echoes into the html. Thank you so much for the tips. I'll let you know how I make out!

If I understand correctly, my approach would be as follows:
/**
*NOTE: I have left out some of your code for splification.
*Pull initial data from DB to fillin the form.
*Be sure to pull id along with other data
*/

//=========================================================== First page
if(isset($_POST['firstPage'])  )  { 
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="update" value=0>
 
    <label class="">Customer</label>
    <input type="text" name="addCustomer">
     
    <label class="">Site Code / Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="addSite" >
    <p>       
    <button name='nextHTML' type='submit'>Next</button>
</form>
} // close firstPage     
 
//====================================================== Calling next HTML
if(isset($_POST['nextHTML'])  )  { 
    $id          = $_POST["id"];
    $update      = $_POST["update"];
    $addCustomer = $_POST["addCustomer"];
    $addSite     = $_POST["addSite"]; // why use a different name than DB field?

$sql= $conn->prepare("
 SELECT *
 FROM DB table
 WHERE addCustomer = 'addCustomer'
 ");

$sql->execute(); 
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {    
 $id          = $row['id'];
 $addCustomer = $row['addCustomer'];
 $addSite     = $row['addSite'];  //Is this a DB field or is it actually 'siteCode'
 
 $siteCode    = $row['siteCode'];
 $urgency     = $row['urgency'];
 $outage      = $row['outage'];
 $date        = $row['date'];
 $requestedBy = $row['requestedBy'];
 $comments    = $row['comments'];       
}

if($update==1) {
    //update DB table
    $update=0;
} // close if


<form action="" method="post">
 <label class="">Customer</label>
     <input type="text" name="addCustomer">
     
 <label class="">Site Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="siteCode" >
     
 <label class="">urgency</label>
      <input type="text" name="urgency" >
     
 <label class="">outage</label>
      <input type="text" name="outage" >
     
 <label class="">date</label>
      <input type="text" name="date" >
     
 <label class="">requestedBy</label>
      <input type="text" name="requestedBy" >
     
 <label class="">Site Code / Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="addSite" >
     
 <label class="">comments</label>
      <input type="text" name="comments" >
     
 <label class="">update</label>
      <input type="button" name="update" value=1>yes
      <input type="button" name="update" value=0 checked>no
 <p>          
 <button name='nextHTML' type='submit'>Next</button>  // see comment below
</form> 
 
} // close nextHTML  


/**
*You can loop the nextHTML section using hidden inputs and switch 
*statements to build the page as data is retrieved from the DB.  
*You can also use if() statements to save updated data within the
*loop
*/

